# Renaming files after folder name

Tags: macos, automator

I need to rename multiple files after the folder that they are in using automator. e.g. index.html renamed to folder1.html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4uK0.jpg

I have about 900 folders with one file in them each all named index.html.

Comment: Why automator? This would be much easier with a shell or perl script, and automator could still call that script.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this in shell, but if you can provide a solution I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is straight forward as using Terminal:

1. Open the Terminal app
2. type in "cd " (note the space) and then drag the folder containing all the folders on to the terminal window. Then press return.
3. Paste this in the terminal window and press enter:

```
for f in `ls -1`; do
  if [[ -f $f/$index.html ]]; then
    cp $f/index.html $f/$f.html; 
  fi;
done
```

Note that I am using the cp command here so it copies the index.html file instead of moving it. Just incase... :)

You can add this to a 'Run Shell Script' action in Automator. Just need to make sure your automator script is saved in the folder with all the sub folders.